# How to check if a value exists in database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to check if a record with the same value already exists in my model.

I have this create function in my trailer model,

```
def create
  trailer = Trailer.create(trailer_params)
  redirect_to :root
end
```

All the trailer records have a `movie_id` value. So without the check something like this can happen,

```
{"id":9,"movie_id":"5","link":"LsjX5dqHLuw"},    
{"id":10,"movie_id":"5","link":"LsjX5dqHLuw"}]
```

2 records with the same link and the same movie_id value.

So I was hoping it's possible to check if a record with the movie_id value already exists. If so, don't do anything. Else create the record.

I've done some research and created this, but this always goes to the `else` state.

```
def create
  if Trailer.exists?(:movie_id => :movie_id).present?
    trailer = Trailer.create(trailer_params)
    redirect_to :root
  else
    redirect_to :root
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you use [`find_or_create_by`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by)?

Comment: vee is right, it is better approach. Also you should be aware of the race condition: it is possible to create two similar objects by the two independent threads.

Comment: @vee how would you include parameters in a `find_or_create_by`? Because the record is being created, but it's empty. `    private

    def trailer_params

      params.require(:trailer).permit(

        :link,

        :movie_id

      )

    end`

Comment: To answer myself `Trailer.find_or_create_by(movie_id: params[:movie_id], link: params[:link])` seems to do the trick.

Comment: @vee if you want, you can answer the question so I can upvote you for your insights. Otherwise I'll provide the answer myself for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You could use first_or_create so:

```
trailer = Trailer.first_or_create(trailer_params)
```

This will either get you the first one with those params or create it if it doesn't exist. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.9/active_record_querying.html#first_or_create

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use ActiveRecord's uniqueness validator? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness

You can use it like so

```
# your Trailer model
class Trailer < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :movie_id, uniqueness: true
end

# Then your controller may look like
def create
  Trailer.create(trailer_params)
  redirect_to :root
end
```